# When the function run. the show me friday but basically its show me Wednesday

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

When the function run. the show me friday but  basically its show me Wednesday. Please Help.

```
<body>
    <button onclick="myfunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click to See To day date</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

function myfunction()
{
    var day;
    switch(new Date().getDate())
        {
            case 0:
                day="Sunday";
                break;
            case 1:
                day="Monday";
                break;
            case 2:
                day="Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                day="Wednesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                day="Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                day="Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                day="Saturday";
                break;

        }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="This day is " +day;
}
```

When the function run. the show me friday but  basically its show me Wednesday

Comment: "the show me friday but basically its show me Wednesday"...what?

Comment: when function run  its show me friday but i show me the this day "means Wednesday" why please help me i'm a new javascript learner

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have `getDate()` which returns the [day of the month](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp). You want `getDay()` which returns the [day of the week.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp)

I'm assuming it's Wednesday August 5th where you are. `getDate()` will return 5, which in your case statement is Friday. If you run `getDay()` it'll return 3, which is Wednesday.

Comment: I understand. Thanks bro :)